# How to create a signed JWT with RSA512 algorithm

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I was trying to create JWT ("JOT") token for make my api call authentic. When ever I try creating token with RSA512 signature, I get back an error saying

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RSA signatures must be computed using an RSA PrivateKey.  The specified key of type javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec is not an RSA PrivateKey.

I am using below code:

```
 SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.RS512;

 long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
  Date now = new Date(nowMillis);
 byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(SECRET_KEY);
 Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, 
                signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());

   JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().claim("uuid", 
    id).setIssuedAt(now).setExpiration(new Date(600000))
    .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey);
```

Note : My "SECRET_KEY" is a string which is a private key generated randomly online . 
my questionis how can I get a Key object from a string encoded with RSA key size as 4096.
4096 since I am using RSA512 encryption, it is recommended to use 4096 key for RSA512

Comment: to verify your token on https://jwt.io/ you have to provide your secret in the right column under `verify signature - your-256-bit-secret`

Comment: The error says something about the key type, but you didn't show details about the `SECRET_KEY`. Can you post the key?

Comment: I used some random Secret key per say
"adsfd564464gfasdf45ds4dffas56f4asd6fda45fads"

Comment: that's sufficient for a HS secret, but certainly not a RSA key. A RSA key looks like this : `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXgIBAAKBgQDHikastc8+I81zCg/qWW8dMr8mqvXQ3qbPAmu0RjxoZVI47tvs...5vg087ZngKfFGR5rozDiTsK5DceTV97K
a3Y+Nzl+XWTxDBWk4YPh2ZlKv402hZEfWBYxUDn5ZkH/bw==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`  On this [site](https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/index.html)   you can create keys for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the info @jsp , it worked but looks like I am not providing right signature . , I was able to generate but still it says Invalid Signature @ jwt.io

Comment: did you paste your secret into the right field on jwt.io(see my first comment above)? If jwt.io doesn't know the secret used, it can't verify the signature.

Comment: jsp : I see below in the signature ,I am using RSA512 encryption format. What to do in this case ?


RSASHA512(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
xxxx
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
,
  
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxx
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your last comment. Do you mean what  key to use to verify on jwt.io? Usually you need the private key to sign the token and the public key to verify it.

Comment: Oh , I am sorry If I have confused with my comments , my mean to ask was : How do I deal adding public or private key to the signature ,

do I need to do generate an RSA in below format and use it as private key ? RSASHA512( base64UrlEncode(header) + "." + base64UrlEncode(payload),privateKey)

Comment: Or would this code take care of it if I am passing right private key ?
signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey);

in

JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().claim("uuid", 
    id).setIssuedAt(now).setExpiration(new Date(600000))
    .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey);

Comment: Hi any clue, every time I try reading cert to get the certificate , I get null in the key for  Kestore. and due to which I am unable to sigh JWT.

Comment: I updated my question. Now I am struck with getting a Key from the String private key encoded with 4096 key size /p12/pfx certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I was not providing an Base64 encoded RSAkey where I was encoding it again to base64 , reason why I was getting this error.

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RSA signatures must be computed using an RSA PrivateKey. The specified key of type javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec is not an RSA PrivateKey.**

I was getting back below error when ever I provide and RSAKey base 64 encoded or an byte code private key

**Base64-encoded key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.**

When ever I am providing a string /byte of private key, it is checking for HMAC algorithm all the time. see below code from JWTBuilder.

```
@Override
public JwtBuilder signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, byte[] secretKey) {
    Assert.notNull(alg, "SignatureAlgorithm cannot be null.");
    Assert.notEmpty(secretKey, "secret key byte array cannot be null or empty.");
    Assert.isTrue(alg.isHmac(), "Key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.");
    this.algorithm = alg;
    this.keyBytes = secretKey;
    return this;
}

@Override
public JwtBuilder signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, String base64EncodedSecretKey) {
    Assert.hasText(base64EncodedSecretKey, "base64-encoded secret key cannot be null or empty.");
    Assert.isTrue(alg.isHmac(), "Base64-encoded key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.");
    byte[] bytes = TextCodec.BASE64.decode(base64EncodedSecretKey);
    return signWith(alg, bytes);
}

@Override
public JwtBuilder signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, Key key) {
    Assert.notNull(alg, "SignatureAlgorithm cannot be null.");
    Assert.notNull(key, "Key argument cannot be null.");
    this.algorithm = alg;
    this.key = key;
    return this;
}
```

Its always best Idea to provide an private Key of type java.security.key and must be a RSA key . I used P12 certificate to load private key.